# Any way to check whether a haar cascade was detected or not?

Tags: opencv, haar-wavelet

The function `detectMultiScale()` returns void, so it is not possible to check whether the the object was detected or not using that function

I wish to pass the frame no., at which the object was detected, to a text file. I don't know how to do that when I can't check whether the cascade was detected or not ?

Should I use `cvHaarDetectObjects()` from C API ?

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale()` is a vector of rectangles. You can check its size:

```
std::vector<cv::Rect> objs;
cascade.detectMultiScale(img, objs, scalefactor, minneighbors);

if (objs.size()) {
  // success
} else {
  // failed
}
```